# Export limited data from the visualisation in powerbi

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have 6 column in powerbi in which we have 100 000 rows. I want to limit that rows by 100 but if we export it to CSV file then I can see all my 100k records.

In my dashboard I am using a Matrix in rows I am using a unique I'd and on column I am using a column and on value I am passing a value.

I tried to limit the data by applying filter on TopN but on exporting it to CSV I am able to see only 100 rows.

Comment: Please avoid using local words like `lakh`. Rest of the world doesn't use them.